# Do we push for consolidating questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Lots of simialr questions around skill challenges, and most of them are having some great answers. But I feel we're into a cascade where they feed off each other. What is the best way to handle this? Does it need some skillful moderator editing? Is this when we move to communitywiki?

Answer (score 2):

No, not community wiki.  The answer is to close the ones that are duplicates, but I'm not sure we have that yet ...

- What makes a skill challenge great?

  - This is about what features a great skill challenge has, not necessarily how to make them great.
- How do you involve all players in a skill challenge?

  - How to craft and execute a challenge that will involve all your players at the table.
- How to make skill checks more then just sequences of die chucking

  - How to involve good role-playing and story development in your skill challenge.
- Need skill challenge ideas for Nature

  - Specific list of ideas for a specific type of challenge.

I don't see those as being duplicates, and I'm not sure their answers will merge well.

Comment: I felt the first three are basically variants, that boil down to "How do I do a good skill challenge that gets my players involved" And the answers seem very similar as a result.

Comment: @Jeremiah There is a reason the close reason is `Exact duplicate`

Comment: I don't see those as duplicates or sensibly mergable. And, D&D4 is a popular system, and Skill Challenges are poorly-understood and easily-done-badly enough that it's inevitable that there will be a lot of nuanced questions about them. I think that a clearinghouse of working wisdom on all facets of such a thing is a valuable outcome of the SE process.

Comment: I think when you see a set of questions like that, it's a great hint that a coherent, thorough investigation of the topic is possible. Sadly, there's no "coherent, thorough investigation of a topic" mechanism on this site. But if someone were to consolidate the information in the answers to those questions and create a "Awesome Skill-Challenge How-To", I think that would be a useful document to link to as a see-also.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even try to merge questions.  Sure there's going to be a lot of questions that are extremely similar, but there's a specific element of the question that makes it unique.  There's a very good reason that there's the "Related Questions" part of the column to the right.  And if anybody comments or answers with a link to the similar questions, they will show up as "Linked Questions" above the related ones. So if you come across one question (say to skill challenges) that seems close to what you're looking for, but not quite, then most likely the other questions will appear as links from said question.

As C. Ross commented on his answer, there's good reasoning behind the wording of "Exact duplicate" for closing a question.

Answer (score 0):

Close 'em as a duplicate and link them over to the one that's substantially the same.  Splitting basically identical responses across questions damages the ability to winnow via voting and encourages pointless duplication.

Comment: I have to admit I like the effect of merging questions more than I like the effect of closing one of a similar set.